# Visual Studio Cordova vs-mda-remote endless loop when .git folder placed inside the project

Tags: git, cordova, visual-studio-2012, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

My structure for Cordova project in VS is as following:

```
Solution_Folder
solution.sln
- solution_root
- - .git
- - js
- - css
....
```

In this case the compilation for IOS never pass the following stage:

```
Extracting /Users/user/remote-builds/builds/1747/upload_1747.tgz to /Users/user/remote-builds/builds/1747/cordovaApp...
GET /build/tasks/1747 200 2ms - 463b
GET /build/tasks/1747 200 5ms - 463b
...
```

It just never ends - I need to kill -9 the process.

If I remove ".git" folder - everything works without problem.

I use SourceTree to manage project on BitBucket.

How can I explain to Visual Studio just ignore this folder and not include it in compilation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your `.git` at the root folder of your project.

By the way, [here is an example of a Visual Studio `.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore).